# Will Ola's default IndexOptimizer job update my stats?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, statistics, ola-hallengren

I just installed Ola Hallengren's [MaintenanceSolution.sql](http://ola.hallengren.com/scripts/MaintenanceSolution.sql) maintenance scripts. After looking at the output of the log generated by the `IndexOptimize - USER_DATABASES` job, I'm concerned that it's not going to update the stats. The reason for my concern is that I see `@UpdateStatistics = NULL` in the parameters listed in the log output:

```
Date and time: 2013-07-16 13:58:24
Server: XXXXX
Version: 10.0.5512.0
Edition: Standard Edition (64-bit)
Procedure: [PROD-PH].[dbo].[IndexOptimize]
Parameters: @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @FragmentationLow = NULL, @FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE', @FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE', @FragmentationLevel1 = 5, @FragmentationLevel2 = 30, @PageCountLevel = 1000, @SortInTempdb = 'N', @MaxDOP = NULL, @FillFactor = NULL, @PadIndex = NULL, @LOBCompaction = 'Y', @UpdateStatistics = NULL, @OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'N', @StatisticsSample = NULL, @StatisticsResample = 'N', @PartitionLevel = 'N', @MSShippedObjects = 'N', @Indexes = NULL, @TimeLimit = NULL, @Delay = NULL, @LockTimeout = NULL, @LogToTable = 'Y', @Execute = 'Y'
Source: http://ola.hallengren.com
```

The motivation behind this is that there is a query that runs once an accounting period (every four weeks) for the date range of the period. The query takes over 20 *minutes* if I do not manually run `sp_updatestats`. The query takes less than 5 *seconds* if the stats are current. The table in question has ~ 1.6M rows but is only growing by ~20K a week. As such, it is nowhere near the 20% auto threshold for a given four week period. Several other tables have a similar growth pattern.

My plan is to schedule this job to run once a week. Will it update the stats as required?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the script does not perform statistics maintenance. The documentation for the script's parameters can be found [here](http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html).

```
Value   Description
================================
ALL     Update index and column statistics.
INDEX   Update index statistics.
COLUMNS Update column statistics.
NULL    Do not perform statistics maintenance. This is the default.
```

So if you let the main script create your maintenance jobs for you, and you wanted to update index and column statistics, then you'd need to edit the IndexOptimize job and add `, @UpdateStatistics='ALL'` into the procedure call.